# Clamshell mode does not work on my MacBook Pro (M1) running macOS 12.5 (Monterey)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, closed-clamshell

I've had this problem since I first bought the Macbook, and I'm still having this problem after messing around with certain settings.

I'm running macOS 12.5 (Monterey), a 14-inch 2021 model, with the Apple M1 Pro chip:

[image: About this Mac]

I have a wide AOC monitor, connected to my laptop via HDMI:

[MacBook Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW0K6.png)

I disabled the power management options that would turn the display off – I set it to never. I also tried setting it to never, even when the macbook is unplugged and plugged. Whenever I connect my laptop to the monitor and close the lid, the laptop locks and the monitor provides a "No signal" message.

I also wiggle the mouse, and press keys on the keyboard in an attempt to wake the device, yet nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is the Mac plugged in to mains power?

Comment: Yes, I always have it connected to power.

Comment: If you have a BT mouse/keyboard connected, try using a (cheap) wired mouse/keyboard.  Those peripherals may be going to sleep and disconnecting.  To use closed clamshell mode, the Mac must see the mouse and keyboard connected.

Comment: @Allan thank you. I don't have a wired mouse (threw my old one out when I got the new MB pro with the magic mouse/keyboard). I'll buy a new one and let you know if that helps

Comment: Don”t spend too much, but it”s always good to have a wired backup in a drawer or shelf somewhere in case things go sideways - like the cat spills wine on the (builtin) keyboard making it unusable.  (Not me personally, but I got the late night call)